# Android openFileInput can't resolve file path

Tags: java, android, fileinputstream

I added external library for file browsing. That library returns selected file path key, but not value.

```
package com.example.dev.nordugrid;
import com.orleonsoft.android.simplefilechooser.ui.FileChooserActivity;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.*;
import android.view.View;
import android.content.Intent;
import java.io.*;

public class jdlFailas extends ActionBarActivity {
final int FILE_CHOOSER = 1;
public String fileSelected;
public String myText;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_jdl_failas);
}

public void openFILE(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(jdlFailas.this, FileChooserActivity.class);
    startActivityForResult(intent, FILE_CHOOSER);

    try {
        FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream ( fileSelected);
        int c;
        String temp="";
        while( (c = fin.read()) != -1){
            temp = temp + Character.toString((char)c);
        }

        fin.close();
        myText = temp.toString();

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
    }
}


public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if ((requestCode == FILE_CHOOSER) && (resultCode == RESULT_OK)) {
        fileSelected = data.getStringExtra(com.orleonsoft.android.simplefilechooser.Constants.KEY_FILE_SELECTED);

        TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.editText2);

        Toast.makeText(this, R.string.pasirinktasFailas + myText, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        textView.setText(myText);
    }
}

public void jdlSave(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(jdlFailas.this, NaujaUzduotis.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_jdl_failas, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

If I put normal filename, program runs normal:

```
   FileInputStream fin = openFileInput("file.txt");
```

Anyway, my main question is "How can I work with files, if I want to use path not string?"

.xml file

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.dev.nordugrid.jdlFailas">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="@string/pridekiteJDL"
    android:id="@+id/textView6"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/prideti"
    android:id="@+id/button12"
    android:onClick="openFILE"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView6"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="@string/rasytiRanka"
    android:id="@+id/textView7"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button12"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView7"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/ikelti"
    android:id="@+id/button13"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:onClick="jdlSave" />
```

There is LogCat code in pastebin link: http://pastebin.com/43kzEgRu

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking here? You can get the (absolute) path from a `File` by calling [`file.getAbsolutePath()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html#getAbsolutePath()), and get a file based on a path by calling one of it's constructors. Either way, a 'path' is generally just represented by a string, and not some sort of special object hierarchy (although nothing's preventing you from creating one, if you really wanted to).

Comment: You forgot to tell and show that you use onActivityResult(). Please tell the type and value of `fileSelected`. Do not use openFileInput but FileOpenStream.

Comment: I can work when  file name is "SOMETHING.txt". But i need to work with selected file, which value is "/storage/sdcard/uzduotis.txt"

Comment: FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream ( fileSelected);

Comment: @greenapps id doesnt helped. I will edit my post and will show you my logcat

Comment: That's not enough. Please show your button on click function where you start the chooser. And answer: "Do you use onActivityResult()?". Show more of your logcat as there is not enough to see yet.

Comment: Your openFILE function cannot work the way you coded it. After startActivityForResult() you cannot just open the file as the user has not yet choosen a file. You should only try to open the file when the user choosed a file. For that you have to inplement onActivityResult().

Comment: @greenapps i posted all what u asked. As i said it before, it works perfect if i wrote filename like  
`FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream("failas.txt")`. But my selected file path is `"/storage/sdcard/uzduotis.txt"` and this functon `FileInputStream` cant work with path like this :)

Comment: @RokasDevolskis - not on Android it won't.  You can't just open a FileInputStream to "failas.txt" and have success as that reference a non-existent file **in the root directory** of the device.   But your full path name such as "/storage/sdcard/uzduotis.txt" should be something which you can pass to a FileInputStream constructor.  So basically you have it backwards - what you think will work won't, while what you think won't work will.

Answer (score 4):

Your question is ultimately due to overlooking the critical difference between

```
FileInputStream fin = openFileInput("file.txt");
```

vs

```
FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream("failas.txt")
```

The first is workable (within an Activity or Service), because `openFileInput()` is an Android-unique method which opens a file **located in the private directory of your application**.

The second is *not workable* on Android, because Java's `FileInputStream(String path)` constructor when given only a filename will attempt to open a file in the working directory, which on Android is the **root directory of the device** - a place where you app cannot have stored any data.

When you are dealing with the External Storage as your path "/storage/sdcard/uzduotis.txt" indicates, you cannot use `openFileInput()`, however in contrast to your assertion you **can** do the following:

```
String path = "/storage/sdcard/uzduotis.txt";
FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(path);
```

Or even literally hardcode it as

```
FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream("/storage/sdcard/uzduotis.txt");
```

Of course overall success, as always, depends on all the usuals such as having a working program, having permission to the External Storage, and having previously created a file at that name and location.

Answer (score 3):

I had similar problem when file_name included a path:

```
InputStream inputStream = context.openFileInput(file_name);
```

Solution was to replace above line with following:

```
file_name=context.getFilesDir() + "/"+file_name;
InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(file_name));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public void openFILE(View view) {
Intent intent = new Intent(jdlFailas.this, FileChooserActivity.class);
startActivityForResult(intent, FILE_CHOOSER);

try {
    FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream ( fileSelected);
    int c;
    String temp="";
    while( (c = fin.read()) != -1){
        temp = temp + Character.toString((char)c);
    }

    fin.close();
    myText = temp.toString();

} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
}
}
```

As said before: You cannot open the file right away as the user first has to select a file. So change to:

```
public void openFILE(View view) {
Intent intent = new Intent(jdlFailas.this, FileChooserActivity.class);
startActivityForResult(intent, FILE_CHOOSER);
}
```

And:

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
if ((requestCode == FILE_CHOOSER) && (resultCode == RESULT_OK)) {
    fileSelected = data.getStringExtra(com.orleonsoft.android.simplefilechooser.Constants.KEY_FILE_SELECTED);
    Toast.makeText(this, fileSelected, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

try {
    FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream ( fileSelected);
    int c;
    String temp="";
    while( (c = fin.read()) != -1){
        temp = temp + Character.toString((char)c);
    }

    fin.close();
    myText = temp.toString();
    TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.editText2);

    Toast.makeText(this, R.string.pasirinktasFailas + myText, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    textView.setText(myText);
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    Toast.makeText(this, "FileNotFoundException: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  } catch (IOException e) {
 e.printStackTrace();       
  Toast.makeText(this, "IOException: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
}
```

Comment: still problem because i cant work with that file path which is `"/storage/sdcard/uzduotis.txt"`

Comment: `i cant work with that file path `. Why not? Any errors? Please tell!! What happens instead? Any exceptions?

Comment: You have requested READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission in manifest file?

Comment: `I will edit my post and will show you my logcat ` You did not post the logcat.

Comment: Please tell which of the four Toast()'s you see from my code.

Comment: There is LogCat code in pastebin link: http://pastebin.com/43kzEgRu i edited my main post :)

Comment: That is the logcat from your wrong sequence of statements. `Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'char[] java.lang.String.toCharArray()' on a null object reference`. Caused by an uninitialized `fileSelected`. You should post the logcat using my code. And you should tell which Toast's you see. Why arent you telling? ANSWER ALL MY QUESTIONS PLEASE. You want to be helped isn't it?

Comment: thank you Sir, all now works perfectly :) can i send u PM and ask one or two other questions? :)

Comment: sorry dude, ur answer helped me a lot of earlier.. i just need to reopen android studio, and ur answer helped me 100% :)

Answer (score 0):

If you have an rooted phone then the you will get the **openFileInput()** from below path

```
/data/data/package name/files/file name (ex config.txt)
```

Other wise check with your **Device file explorer** with the same path